# No puedo sumar valores metidos por el prompt

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando aprender JS, y me puse a mi mismo un ejercicio para aprender los operadores, y cómo jugar con ellos.

El caso es, que al pedir los números por el prompt, cabe la posibilidad de poner texto, me gustaría saber cómo validar que sea un campo int, he leído que con isNAN se puede hacer, pero no entiendo muy bien cómo implementarlo.

El segundo problema, es que al sumar números, me los suma como si fueran valores de texto (10+10=1010), pero al restarlos, lo hace bien.

¿Hay alguna solución? Sobre todo para lo segundo, que es lo que más me interesa...

(Dejo aquí el fragmento de código)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Operaciones</title>
</head>

<script>
    var numerando = prompt('Escribe un número');
    while (!numerando) {
        numerando = prompt('Escribe un número por favor');
    }
    console.log(numerando);
    var numerado = prompt('Escribe otro número');
    while (!numerado) {
        numerado = prompt('Escribe otro número por favor');
    }
    console.log(numerado);
    
    function sumandos(a, b){
        var a = numerando;
        var b = numerado;
        var result = a + b;
        alert(result);
        alert('El resultado de ' + a + ' mas ' + b + ' es igual a ' + result);
    }
    function restandos(a, b){
        var a = numerando;
        var b = numerado;
        var result = a - b;
        alert(result);
        alert('El resultado de ' + a + ' menos ' + b + ' es igual a ' + result);
    }

</script>

<body>
<button onclick="sumandos()">Sumar</button>
<button onclick="restandos()">Restar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para convertir un texto en número entero (o [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) si quieres números decimales).

```js
parseInt('123') // Devuelve 123
parseInt('a') // Devuelve NaN (significa "Not a Number")
parseInt('1.68') // Devuelve 1

parseFloat('123') // Deuelve 123
parseFloat('a') // Deuelve NaN
parseFloat('1.68') // Deuelve 1.68
```

Quizá quieras usar también [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) antes de convertir a número, para asegurarte de que son números. En tu código un buen sitio sería en el bucle que recibe números:

```js
var numerado = prompt('Escribe otro número');
while (!numerado || isNaN(numerado)) {
    numerado = prompt('Escribe otro número por favor');
}
```

Comment: Buah, perfectísimo, ahora el código hace exactamente lo que quiero. Editaré la pregunta para que el que necesite un código parecido o como ejemplo lo tenga.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que JS, al sumar cadenas de texto, lo que hace es concatenarlas, pero si restas, sí hace la conversión de datos de cadena de texto a número. Tu solución más sencilla es hacer un casting a la hora de asignar el valor.

```
<script>
    var numerando = prompt('Escribe un número');
    while (!numerando) {
        numerando = prompt('Escribe un número por favor');
    }
    console.log(numerando);
    var numerado = prompt('Escribe otro número');
    while (!numerado) {
        numerado = prompt('Escribe otro número por favor');
    }
    console.log(numerado);
    
    function sumandos(a, b){
        var a = parseInt(numerando);
        var b = parseInt(numerado);
        var result = a + b;
        alert(result);
        alert('El resultado de ' + a + ' mas ' + b + ' es igual a ' + result);
    }
    function restandos(a, b){
        var a = parseInt(numerando);
        var b = parseInt(numerado);
        var result = a - b;
        alert(result);
        alert('El resultado de ' + a + ' menos ' + b + ' es igual a ' + result);
    }

</script>

<body>
<button onclick="sumandos()">Sumar</button>
<button onclick="restandos()">Restar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfectísimo!!! Creí que iba a ser mucho más complicado! Muchas gracias. Entonces parseINT lo que hace es convertir el valor de texto a un valor int directamente? para saber cómo funciona y hacer mis apuntes correspondientes

Comment: Así es, si en tu caso quieres también que el usuario te lo convierta a double o float, la conversión sería parseFloat(...) en vez de parseInt(...) @Aaronibio

Comment: Una opción que también funciona es el operador + : `let a = +(numerando);` transforma numerando a number si se puede.